# Guardar archivo en directorio, desde la vista - Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

Tengo una aplicación con la cual subo archivos, y posteriormente esos archivos son consultados,
los archivos tienen la siguiente nomenclatura: `EJEMPLO_7777_AAAA.pdf`

Si el archivo pertenece al grupo `7777`, el archivo es guardado en la ruta:

```
upload_to='Archivos/Grupo/7777'
```

Si el archivo es del grupo `7746`, es guardado en la ruta:

```
upload_to='Archivos/Grupo/7746'
```

Sin embargo son 31 grupos, por lo tanto tengo que crear 31 tablas o modelos para
poder guardar en cada tabla los archivos pertenecientes a cada grupo.

El punto es que quiero validar el grupo y a partir del grupo guardar el archivo en su ruta especifica, con esto los archivos estarán guardados en una sola tabla.

Así es como lo hago:

```
if grupo=='7777':
    datos=ArchivosGrupo7777() # Nombre de la tabla actual
    datos.usuario=usuarioSesion
    datos.save()

if grupo=='7746':
    datos=ArchivosGrupo7746() # Nombre de la tabla actual
    datos.usuario=usuarioSesion
    datos.save()
```

Sin embargo la idea es que no existan demasiadas tablas y que sea algo así:

```
if grupo=='7777':
    datos=Archivos()/*Nombre de la tabla
    datos.usuario=usuarioSesion
    datos.save(directorio='Archivos/Grupo/7777')

if grupo=='7746':
    datos=Archivos()/*Nombre de la tabla
    datos.usuario=usuarioSesion
    datos.save(directorio='Archivos/Grupo/7746')


Modelos-Ejemplo

class ArchivosGrupo7777(models.Model):
    fecha = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    proyecto=models.CharField(default='Proyecto 7777',max_length=30)
    ruta = models.FileField(upload_to='Archivos/Grupo/7777')
    usuario=models.ForeignKey(User)

class ArchivosGrupo7746(models.Model):
    fecha = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    proyecto=models.CharField(default='Proyecto 7746',max_length=30)
    ruta = models.FileField(upload_to='Archivos/Grupo/7746')
    usuario=models.ForeignKey(User)
```

Answer (score 2):

yo creo que no es necesario que tengas un modelo por cada grupo de archivos, lo puedes hacer dinamicamente, teniendo el `grupo`como un parametro algo así:

```
class Archivos(modesl.Model):

    grupo = models.CharField(max_length=3)
    fecha = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    proyecto=models.CharField(default='Proyecto 7777',max_length=30)
    ruta = models.FileField(upload_to='Archivos/Grupo/7777')
    usuario=models.ForeignKey(User)

# en la view
grupo = '777' # asumiendo que el grupo es valido
Archivos.create(
        grupo=grupo,
        proyecto='Proyecto %s' % (grupo),
        ruta='Archivos/Grupo/%s' %(grupo),
        usuario=usuarioSesion
        )
```

De esta manera tendras en una sola tabla todos los archivos, y añadiendo el
campo grupo puedes hacer group by para obtener todos los del mismo grupo

Ahora si lo que quieres es tener una tabla por cada grupo, no veo realmente
como eso pueda ser practico, pero puedes usar un Generic ForeignKey, de tal
manera que tendrías una tabla archivo con un ForeignKey "dinamico" el cual
seria el grupo, te dejo un link de la documentación:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/2.1/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#generic-relations

Comment: ¿Que es lo que indicas con? %s y %

Comment: es valido de esta forma? `a=archuivos()
grupo = '777'

a.create(
 grupo=grupo,
 proyecto='Proyecto %s' % (grupo),
 ruta='Archivos/Grupo/%s' %(grupo),
 usuario=usuarioSesion
 )`

Comment: Como se aplica el save()? en este caso con `archivos.create() archivos.save()`

Comment: Estoy implementandolo de esta forma, sin embargo no me crea la carpeta en la ruta especificada pero si hace la inserciòn en la BDD

Comment: `a=ArchivosHospitality7734.objects.create(
                                proyecto='Proyecto %s' % (familiaMoi),
                                ruta='Archivos/Grupo/%s' %(item),
                                estacion=lineaPdf,
                                familia=familiaPdf,
                                feature=feature,
                                
                                
                                usuario=usuarioSesion

                                )
                        a.save()`

Comment: Hola el uso de %s y s solo es el formato los strings, puedes https://pyformat.info/, ahora al usar el método create, te ahorras la necesidad de usas el save, puedes leer la documentación de esto: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/instances/ 
En cuando a los directorios verifica que el path sea correcto

Comment: Mi ruta esta bien, y aun sigue insertándolo en la BDD pero sin aparecer en el directorio

Comment: Puedes revisar esto en la documentación de [Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/2.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField.storage)